# rxjs, node, subscription memory leak in handler

Tags: node.js, rxjs

Let's say you have an `express` style handler function like this:

```
(req, res, next) => {
    const requestedProgramIDs = req.body.programIDs;
    // assume all data is in a cache observable
    cache$.filter(data => requestedProgramIDs.indexOf(data.id) >= 0)
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(programs => res.end(JSON.stringify(programs)))
};
```

My question is will this subscription leak memory? I'm concerned that if I just `unsubscribe` at the end of the function then there is no guarantee that the subscription code will execute.

My solutions thoughts are as follows:

- use a `.take(1)` to ensure unsubscription
- If the `scheduler` for the observable is synchronous, then the unsubscription will be synchronous and I can just tack it on the end of the function.

questions:

- am I right in thinking the subscription will leak?
- if, so  how would you recommend I deal with (prevent) the leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Subscribing and Unsubscribing* section of the [*Observable Contract*](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) states:

> When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.

So if your `cache$` observable completes - which it must do for the `toArray` operator to emit a array - there is no need to call `unsubscribe`. It won't leak, as long as the composed observable completes or errors.

Also, you might want to wire up `next`, so that errors are forwarded to Express:

```
.subscribe(programs => res.end(JSON.stringify(programs)), next)
```